# Browser @font-face TTF support

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-face

I would like to use a custom font that I have in **TTF** format only, so I need to execute a script that would detect a support of `@font-face` with `TTF` format. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

TTF is supported by [a lot of browsers](http://caniuse.com/ttf). I wrote a check to test `@font-face` support by trying to render a small custom TTF font. If you disable the test for IE8 and below from this script (which uses an EOT font), you'll have the test you're looking for.

You can find the script here: https://github.com/RoelN/font-face-render-check

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of posts here that get into this subject in great detail.

Just to get you going if you only have a TTF file you can use [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to convert the TTF file into other common web fonts.

These will help provide fallbacks for all of the different major browsers

The site will also help you with the generation and usage of the @font-face tag in CSS to embed the font correctly.

Comment: Yes there is a lot of options how to check support of `@font-face`, but I am looking for support of this feature with TTF. Conversion of TTF into other file format is not an option here. The question/task is strict. I am not looking for workaround, such you have suggested. Thank you for you answer anyway, it may help other users to find solution for their similar issues...

Comment: You should rephrase the question and be more explicit because if anyone else reads you have TTF format they're going to think you need help converting it. For current versions of browsers they almost all should support TTF (http://caniuse.com/ttf)

Comment: It stays "**detect a support of @font-face with TTF format**", which I believe is enough explicit.